# Why can't take gravity = 10 why velocity is given?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, power

**What is this about?** I have a question and there are two ways to solve it. One is wrong and other is right and I wanted to know why was the wrong one wrong.

**What do I want to know?** In the wrong approach why I could not take gravity?

**Question - A tube-well pumps out 2400 kg of water per minute. If water is coming out with a velocity of 3 m/s, what is power of the pump?**

**Solution - 1 (This one is wrong)**

[image]

**Solution - 2 - (This one is right)**

[image]

Comment: Because you don't know the real acceleration which "pumping force" gives to the water going up the tube. For the correct upwards acceleration- you can start from good power answer and work backwards to know correct acceleration:
$$   a_{pump} = \frac {180 ~W}{40 kg ×  3 m/s} = 1.5~m/s^2$$
Besides $10 m/s^2$ is gravity induced acceleration downwards the pump, but this is not what you want at all. You need **up-wards** acceleration which is the net result of gravity force given acceleration and pump "raw force" given acceleration which acts in diferent direction than gravity. That's why.

Comment: You don't know the acceleration. You have used 10 which seems to be (close to) the gravitational acceleration. But this acceleration is only achieved when we are falling in a free fall due to gravity. If another force than gravity is pushing, then you need to know the acceleration caused by this other force in order to use the formula you wanted to use. Since you don't know that, using your formula won't be helpful.

Comment: I think you may have been caught by your intuition.  They call it a "well pump," and intuitively a well pump does hard work against gravity.  However, to include that power, we would need to know how high it is pumping the water.  That isn't provided.  The problem is only actually asking about the power needed to have an inlet velocity of 0m/s and an outlet velocity of 3m/s.  It's actually ignoring the "well" part of the story all together.

Answer (score 2):

This can't be used because $g$ is the acceleration due to gravity, not the acceleration of the water. $a = \frac{dv}{dt} = 0$ and that formula doesn't work.

You would want to use the formula $P = mav$ when a is the acceleration of the water.